# SQLAlchemy parse a large file

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How to parse a big file (50-100GB) into my database using SQLAlchemy? Let's say I have two tables.

```
import collections
import re
import Bio.SeqIO
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer, String, Text, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ClauseElement

Base = declarative_base()

class Protein_sequence(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'protein_sequence'
    prot_seq_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    prot_seq = Column(Text, unique=True)
    protein_annotation = relationship('Protein', back_populates='protein_sequence')

class Protein(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'protein_annotation'
    prot_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    prot_seq_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('protein_sequence.prot_seq_id'))
    prot_acc = Column(Text, unique=True)
    prot_name = Column(Text)
    protein_sequence = relationship('Protein_sequence', back_populates='protein_annotation')

def parse_fasta(path, prot_db='unknown', taxon_name=None, taxon_id=None):
    """Parsing a fasta file (UniProt or NCBInr)."""

    prot = collections.OrderedDict()

    for record in Bio.SeqIO.parse(path, 'fasta'):

        prot['seq'] = str(record.seq)
        desc = record.description

        gi_num = re.findall('^gi\|([0-9]+)(?:\||\s|$)', desc)
        if gi_num:
            prot['prot_gi'] = gi_num[0]
        desc = re.sub('^gi\|([0-9]+)(?:\||\s|$)', '', desc)

        prot_db = re.findall('^([^|]+)\|', desc)
        if prot_db:
            prot_db = prot_db[0]
        prot['prot_db'] = prot_db

        prot_acc = re.findall('^[^|]+\|([^ ]+)', desc)[0]
        prot['prot_acc'] = prot_acc

        prot['prot_name'] = re.findall('^[^ ]+ (.+)', desc)[0]

        yield prot

def prot_db_from_fasta():
    """Create tables in SQLite database. Input fasta file."""

    db = 'sqlite:///proteomic.db'
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    Session = sqlalchemy.orm.sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    conn = engine.connect()

    p = 'prot.fasta'

    for prot in parse_fasta(p):

        # prot is dictionary storing info about protein
        protein_sequence = Protein_sequence(prot_seq=prot['seq'])
        session.add(protein_sequence)

        try:
            session.commit()
        except:
            session.rollback()

        # choose only columns in table protein_annotation
        cols = [c.name for c in Protein.__table__.columns]
        annotation = {key: prot[key] for key in cols if key in prot}

        annotation['prot_seq_id'] = protein_sequence.prot_seq_id
        protein_annotation = Protein(**annotation)
        session.add(protein_annotation)

    session.commit()
    conn.close()

# run function to insert data into database
prot_db_from_fasta()
```

The problem is that I need information about sequence ID (for annotation table) and in the same time insert sequence into database unless it is already there. Using SQLAlchemyCore will not help, the problem is I am using session commit in every for cycle. And it is very slow. If I use this script for 70MB big file, it takes 17 sec. If I use sqlite3 instead of SQLAlchemy it takes only 0.3 sec.

I know it is better to insert data in one big transaction but how to do it. I will not get back sequence ID to use them for my protein annotation.

There is also example of fasta file.

```
>gi|115646|sp|P02662.2|CASA1_BOVIN Alpha-S1-casein
MKLLILTCLVAVALARPKHPIKHQGLPQEVLNENLLRFFVAPFPEVFGKEKVNELSKDIGSESTEDQAME
DIKQMEAESISSSEEIVPNSVEQKHIQKEDVPSERYLGYLEQLLRLKKYKVPQLEIVPNSAEERLHSMKE
GIHAQQKEPMIGVNQELAYFYPELFRQFYQLDAYPSGAWYYVPLGTQYTDAPSFSDIPNPIGSENSEKTT
MPLW

>gi|115654|sp|P02663.2|CASA2_BOVIN Alpha-S2-casein
MKFFIFTCLLAVALAKNTMEHVSSSEESIISQETYKQEKNMAINPSKENLCSTFCKEVVRNANEEEYSIG
SSSEESAEVATEEVKITVDDKHYQKALNEINQFYQKFPQYLQYLYQGPIVLNPWDQVKRNAVPITPTLNR
EQLSTSEENSKKTVDMESTEVFTKKTKLTEEEKNRLNFLKKISQRYQKFALPQYLKTVYQHQKAMKPWIQ
PKTKVIPYVRYL
```

So what is good practice to insert data into database.

[Picture of my proteomic database.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPS4d.png)

Comment: For starters, you don't need to commit in a loop to fetch the assigned primary key values. A [flush](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) will suffice. But that's not going to help you a lot, though. [An ORM is the wrong tool for huge bulk operations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/performance.html#i-m-inserting-400-000-rows-with-the-orm-and-it-s-really-slow), in general.

Comment: A flush() is helpful but I will lost previous protein_annotation session after rollback() . So only raw connection is possible:(.

Comment: Ah your data may contain `Protein_sequence` duplicates? Use a savepoint, or something akin to merge. All in all I think you should use a temporary table, populated from your input, and operate from there. What DB are you using underneath?

Comment: Is this one time operation or do you need to programmatically do it over and over again for different large files?

Comment: Note that it'd help helping you, if you'd provide a [mcve]. Namely working Python (pretty much copy-paste-and-run), the table schemas involved, a (small) sample of your data, and possibly a small sample of a prepopulated table so that it'd demonstrate handling duplicates. And the name of the DB you are using – you mention sqlite passingly in a sentence, but is that what you're actually using?

Comment: Protein_sequence contains column with unique sequence string. I am not sure what does it means Protein_sequence duplicates. I guess it should not. I will study the possibility to use temporary table. I am beginner in using databases, so...

Comment: A duplicate is a duplicate, though I might've used the word in a bit confusing way – usually it'd mean that the primary key of an object you're trying to insert exists already. In this case I meant that if the `prot_seq` of `Protein_sequence(prot_seq=prot['seq'])` exists already, then it violates the unique constraint (when you add the [transient](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_state_management.html) model object to the session and commit).

Comment: I updated example to be complete. I am using sqlite but I wanted to switch to postgresql. That's why I tried to use SQLAlchemy instead of sqlite3 module.

Comment: This operation will be done several times, not really often and usually for 100 MB up to 1GB file. And one time for 70GB file. Sequence and accession will be often repeated in a new file so unique constraint should take care about non-redundancy.